# Deadlock in two forms

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have two simple windows on separate threads with button. By pressing button in one window program sends message to another window and vice versa. Received messsage initiates message box with form name.  Usually I have deadlock, when it is not possible press button on messagebox. Only one combination exist - when form A is active press button on B form.  Why it causes deadlock in all other cases?

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <iostream>
class MyWnd;

extern MyWnd *Bwnd;
extern MyWnd *Awnd;
#define IDC_BTN       100
using namespace std;
class MyWnd :public CFrameWnd
{
public:
    CButton m_wndPushButton;
    MyWnd(const wchar_t * txt  )
    {

        Create(NULL,txt);
    }


    afx_msg LRESULT OnMessageCust(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        wchar_t* p = new wchar_t[20];

        this->GetWindowText(p,20);
        AfxMessageBox(p);

        delete(p);

    return 0;
    }


    afx_msg void OnPushButtonClicked ()
    {
        //SendMessage(WM_USER + 1, 0, 0);
        if (this==Bwnd) { TRACE("Awnd"); Awnd->SendMessage(WM_USER + 1, 0, 0) ; }
        if (this==Awnd) {TRACE("Bwnd"); Bwnd->SendMessage(WM_USER + 1, 0, 0);}

        //AfxMessageBox(L"Hello");
    } ;

    afx_msg  int OnCreate (LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs)  {

        if (CWnd::OnCreate (lpcs) == -1)   return -1;   

        CRect rectbutton(50,50,150,150); 

        m_wndPushButton.Create (_T ("Start"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |  BS_PUSHBUTTON, rectbutton, this, IDC_BTN);

        return 0;  

    } ;

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP ()

};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP (MyWnd, CFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_CREATE ()   
    ON_BN_CLICKED (IDC_BTN, OnPushButtonClicked)  
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_USER + 1 ,OnMessageCust)

    ON_WM_PAINT ()
    ON_WM_DESTROY()
END_MESSAGE_MAP ()



MyWnd *Bwnd;
MyWnd *Awnd;


class modHolder : public CWinThread
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(modHolder)

protected:
    modHolder()
    {

    };           
    virtual ~modHolder()
    {

    };

public:
//MyWnd *Bwnd;  
    virtual BOOL InitInstance()
        {

            Bwnd = new MyWnd(L"B window");

            ShowWindow (Bwnd->m_hWnd,SW_SHOW);
            Bwnd->UpdateWindow();
            return true;
        };
    virtual int ExitInstance()
        {
            delete(Bwnd);
            return CWinThread::ExitInstance();
        };

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(modHolder, CWinThread)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(modHolder, CWinThread)



class MyApp :public CWinApp
{
    //MyWnd *Awnd; 
public:
    BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        Awnd = new MyWnd(L"A window");

        m_pMainWnd = Awnd;
        m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

        CWinThread* pThread= AfxBeginThread( RUNTIME_CLASS(modHolder) );


        return TRUE;
    }
};



MyApp theApp ;
```

Comment: Having UI in different threads is generally a bad idea.

Comment: I agree with this, but from educational point of view what is concrete wrong with this code?

Comment: For education: There's hardly anything right with this code. `operator new[]()` requires cleanup with `delete[]()`. Custom messages start at `WM_APP`; `WM_USER+1` is reserved for the author of a window class. Setting an arbitrary limit of 20 characters for a call to `GetWindowText()` is questionable (a violation of the zero-one-infinity rule). Maybe you should learn the Windows API and C++ first, and move on to multithreading later. Once you are **intimately** familiar with all three you may try to write a multithreaded GUI (I wouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple: You didn't used m_pMainFrame in the second thread.

What happens:

1. Click on the button in your MyApp Thread.
2. The message is sent to the second window.
3. The current MyApp thread is suspended until the second thread will return.
4. In the second modHolder thread. The message is received by the message loop.
5. Your handler is called and AfxMessageBox is launched.
6. The internal code for AfxMessageBox now tries to get the parent window. Nobody set a parent window for this thread and usualy CWinThread::m_pMainWnd is used.
7. Your application finally uses a CWinApp m_pMainFrame and this is the currently blocked window A?
8. The message box routine tries to disable the window (that causes another SendMessage to AWnd)
9. Deadlock: Window A waits for window B, window B waits for a reaction of Window A

That's a reason why two UI threads must be designed very carefully. A newbie should avoid it at all.

BTW: You code is horrible even for a test code. Learn more basics. i.E: Why do you allocate storage with new, when you can use CString and GetWindowText?